# Unable to get AWS powershell comands working in Windows-10

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-powershell

I want to run some AWS commands using PowerShell scripts in windows. I went ahead and ran this below command.

```
Install-Module AWSPowerShell
```

The module got installed without any error. But I'm getting below error when I try to do "Set-AWSCredentials" 
[image]

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages as they are mostly unreadable [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Did you try the solution recommended in the error message?

Comment: @Olaf yes, I tried the solution recommended. Sorry, it's only the access key and secret key that I have struck over. Cause its sensitive information.

Comment: Do not add additional information as comments. Add it to your question. And what happend when you imported the module?

Comment: @Olaf, It actually shows nothing.. No error.. nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to import the module installed. Almost you can use the following command *Get-Module* to check if the module is imported and installed in the current session of powershell execution.

```
Import-Module AWSPowerShell

Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

Answer (score 0):

adding -Force solved it for me where "Import-Module AWSPowerShell" still showed no effect.
`Import-Module AWSPowerShell -Force`